# The exit status code '1' says something went wrong: stderr: "'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal command or ... "

Tags: windows, laravel, laravel-5, environment-variables, wkhtmltopdf

I am getting this:

```
> The exit status code '1' says something went wrong:
stderr: "'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal command
or external, an executable program or a batch file."
```

I am using wkhtmltopdf to generatepdf under laravel, and it is working fine. I use windows for local project. Now when I try to generate it, I get this error. Nothing change, laravel updated and just my .env file I accidentally deleted. 
I create a new one, but either I get a totally blank page for all my project or I get this error when I do ajax request for generating pdf.

I try in .env (by phpdotenv 3):

```
WKHTMLTOPDF='"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf"'
```

config/snappy.php:

```
<?php

return array(


    'pdf' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary'  => env('WKHTMLTOPDF'),
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => array(),
        'env'     => array(),
    ),
    'image' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary'  => env('WKHTMLTOIMAGE'),
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => array(),
        'env'     => array(),
    ),

    'binary' => env('WKHTMLTOPDF'),
);
```

Comment: Can you post your `config/snappy.php` file code here?

Comment: `'"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf"'` or `"\"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf\""`, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: config/snappy.php added. this is the last version I have after editing several times

Comment: @JosefZ yes ` '"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf"' `  works when I put in snappy.php. But what is the best syntax if I want to put in .env ?

Answer (score 2):

Escape your space in your path of wkhtmltopdf bin

Try this:

```
WKHTMLTOPDF='"C:\\Program\ Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf"'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
WKHTML_PDF_BINARY="\"\"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe\"\""
WKHTML_IMG_BINARY="\"\"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe\"\""
```

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

Simply do

`WKHTMLTOPDF="C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf"`

This works for me.

Comment: Are you usig phpdotev 3? if no, it is normal this works.My issue is with phpdotenv 3